# Git: How to create a Patch file showing only the changes?

Tags: git

I have made some changes in multiple files in different directories.

I would like to create a single patch file showing only the changes I have made.

I have tried using:

```
git format-patch -1 61a19d82038aca3c5d6d54b38d2739ac075fef84
```

but the result file is the whole source file is showing minus sign and after that section, there is a plus sign section of the same source file, which includes the changes I have made.

Example:

```
-
- Here is the some code of the entire file
- Here is the some more code of the entire file
-
+
+ Here is the some code of the entire file
+ Changes here.
+ Here is the some more code of the entire file
+
```

How do I create a patch file showing only the lines of codes that I have changed. Not the whole file?

Thanks.

Comment: The lines with only leading `+` are due to line endings. For example, the original line ending is `LF` but the new one is `CRLF`. It can happen when you edit the file on Windows. You can set the editor to show invisible characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing the entire file as changed is due to a difference in [line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).

You can either [configure Git to automatically convert line endings](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_formatting_and_whitespace) for you or, more simply, tell `format-patch` to ignore them by passing the [`--ignore-space-change`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt---ignore-space-change) ([`-b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#Documentation/git-format-patch.txt--b)) option:

> Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be equivalent.

In your case, you would say:

```
git format-patch -b -1 61a19d82038aca3c5d6d54b38d2739ac075fef84
```